# Matching Multiple Fields Inversely on Another Line

Tags: bash, awk

The logic I'd like to write is as follows:

**If column #1 of the current line matches column #3 of any other row AND if column #3 of the current line also matches column #1 of the row, print column #1 and column #2 of both lines on the same line.**

Below is my input file:

**Interface Table (input):**

```
NODE1   eth1    NODE2
NODE1   eth2    NODE3
NODE2   eth1    NODE1
NODE2   eth2    NODE4
NODE3   eth1    NODE1
NODE3   eth2    NODE4
NODE4   eth1    NODE2
NODE4   eth2    NODE3
```

**Link Table (desired output):**

```
NODE1   eth1    NODE2   eth1
NODE1   eth2    NODE3   eth1
NODE2   eth2    NODE4   eth1
NODE3   eth2    NODE4   eth2
```

Below is a network diagram that illustrates this.

```
NODE1--eth1---link1---eth1--NODE2
|                             |
eth2                         eth2
|                             |
|                             |
link2       NETWORK         link3
|                             |
|                             |
eth1                         eth1
|                             |
NODE3--eth2---link4---eth2--NODE4
```

**EDIT 2018-03-01**

I added an additional column and would also like to print that.

**Input:**

```
NODE1   adapter1    eth1    NODE2
NODE1   adapter2    eth2    NODE3
NODE2   adapter1    eth1    NODE1
NODE2   adapter2    eth2    NODE4
NODE3   adapter1    eth1    NODE1
NODE3   adapter2    eth2    NODE4
NODE4   adapter1    eth1    NODE2
NODE4   adapter2    eth2    NODE3
```

**Output**

```
NODE1   adapter1    eth1    adapter1    NODE2   eth1
NODE1   adapter2    eth2    adapter1    NODE3   eth1
NODE2   adapter2    eth2    adapter2    NODE4   eth1
NODE3   adapter2    eth2    adapter2    NODE4   eth2
```

Comment: your description does not capture your requirement precisely. **next** in your requirement really means any other line that follows, not **next**. i can provide a python script that does that if you want to.

Comment: That would be great.  I'd like to see how this is done in Python and have the option to use that.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. We can't fix things that we can't see. From your tags, I'd expect to see an attempt to solve your problem using bash and awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '$3","$1 in a{ print $3, a[$3","$1], $1, $2 }{ a[$1","$3]=$2 }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
NODE1   eth1    NODE2   eth1
NODE1   eth2    NODE3   eth1
NODE2   eth2    NODE4   eth1
NODE3   eth2    NODE4   eth2
```

---

*Bonus* solution for your additional condition:

```
awk '($4,$1) in a{ print $4, a[$4,$1], $2, $1, $3 }{ a[$1,$4]=$2 OFS $3 }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
NODE1   adapter1    eth1    adapter1    NODE2   eth1
NODE1   adapter2    eth2    adapter1    NODE3   eth1
NODE2   adapter2    eth2    adapter1    NODE4   eth1
NODE3   adapter2    eth2    adapter2    NODE4   eth2
```

Comment: you may want to change `$3$1` to `($3,$1)`, otherwise it may create false matches.  e.g. `one book` with `on ebook`

Comment: @karakfa, it was just so at my 1st attempt, but I've shortened it assuming that values will come in a static format `node<number>`. Now, made a rollback (see edit history)

Comment: That might bite me down the road.  Can you provide that?  I tried "awk '($3,$1) ..." and it stopped matching.  I also tried it within the brackets but received a syntax error?

Comment: inventing a delimiter not required, you can use `($3,$1) in` and `a[$3,$1]`

Comment: I changed one thing and I can't seem to get this to work.  Edits have been made to the original post.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Roman can you add a check that if there is not a match, it prints "no_match"?